# Item alignment fail on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following `Jade / HTML`:

```
  a.service.comparison(ng-href="...")
    .icon
      i.far.fa-map-signs
    .content
      span.d-block.title Compare energy deals
      span.text Looking for a better energy deal?
    .arrow
      button.btn(type="button")
        i.fas.fa-chevron-circle-right
```

And `Less / CSS`:

```
.service {
    color: @grey-dark;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    max-width: 100%;

    .icon {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right: none;
      border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
      font-size: 28px;
      padding: 10px 15px;

      i {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        .transform(translateY(-70%));
        width: 40px;
      }
    }

    .content {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right: none;
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding: 15px;

      .title {
        color: @green-medium;
        font-size: 17px;
      }
    }

    .arrow {
      min-height: 100%;

      .btn {
        background: @green-medium;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        color: white;
        padding: 0;
        width: 35px;
        height: 100%;

        i {
          position: relative;
          top: 50%;
          .transform(translateY(20%));
          vertical-align: top;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It looks nice on all Browsers, the left icon is in centre and the right green button has a 100% height and fill the box... Unfortunately on iOS Safari it looks differently: the left icon is on top and the right button doesn't fill the entire box height as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix this? Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Transform Mixin:

```
.transform(@string){
    -webkit-transform: @string;
    -moz-transform:      @string;
    -ms-transform:       @string;
    -o-transform:        @string;
  transform:         @string;
}
```

Comment: What's in the .transform mixin? Also I am not sure which version of iOS you have but you can try it by adding webkit prefix for the flex rules. And I think for safari the height 100% might not work? I had something similar but forgot the cause. Can you post the generated html markup/css so we can play around with it

Comment: Added mixin. Thanks.

Comment: So, I just fixed the left icon to in the center by adding `display: flex` to `.icon` and removing positioning properties from the icon. The `height: 100%` on the button is the only thing I should fix...

Comment: Sorry I don't know how jade works so not seeing the markup really hinders me. The usual vertical center using the method you had, is to set `.transform(translateY(-50%))` with the top 50% that you had

Comment: Thanks, just fixed using `flex` on `.arrow` removing all references to `height` on `.arrow` and `.btn`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can post your own answer so it will be useful for future readers, if you really don't want to post an answer then I suggest you delete the question